# Error in finding a point within a GeoJSON file

Tags: python, geojson, shapely, point-in-polygon

I have a GeoJSON of all the marine zones of the world downloaded from the FAO (https://data.apps.fao.org/map/catalog/srv/eng/catalog.search#/metadata/ac02a460-da52-11dc-9d70-0017f293bd28). I want to see whether or not a coordinate lies in the ocean but using python I am getting the incorrect value.

The coordinate in question is long = 157.5314783333, lat = 0.9013516667

I am using the shapely lib in Python and have tried both within and contain methods.

I have also tried to simplify the polygon using validate and simplify methods of the shapely lib.

This is the google collab file - https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1dJkT9k2sVl7fFYkic7iT9BfysRr5f8E3?usp=sharing

Below I've used the within and contain method of shapely -

```py
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon, shape

def identify_ocean(longitude, latitude):
  point = Point(longitude, latitude)
  i = 0
  print(point)
  for feature in geojson_file['features']:
    
    # Trying with within method

    # i += len(feature['geometry']['coordinates'][0][0])
    # print(len(feature['geometry']['coordinates'][0][0]))
    # if Point(point).within(Polygon(feature['geometry']['coordinates'][0][0])):
    #   print(feature['properties']['OCEAN'])
    #   return feature['properties']['OCEAN']
    
    # Trying with contains method

    polygon = shape(feature['geometry'])
    if polygon.contains(point):
        print("yay")

  return False

identify_ocean(157.5314783333, 0.9013516667)
# print("finalllllllllllll = ",i)
```

Output -

```
GEOSException: TopologyException: side location conflict at 126.00848823529411 9.7046176470588552. This can occur if the input geometry is invalid.
```

Below I've used the simplify then contain method of shapely -

```py
import json
from shapely.geometry import shape, Point


# Load the GeoJSON object
with open('FAO_AREAS_CWP.json', 'r') as f:
    geojson = json.load(f)

for feature in geojson['features']:
  # Convert the GeoJSON object to a Shapely geometry
  geometry = shape(feature['geometry'])

  # Simplify the geometry
  simplified_geometry = geometry.simplify(tolerance=0.5)

  # Check if the point is contained within the simplified geometry
  point = Point(157.5314783333, 0.9013516667)
  if simplified_geometry.contains(point):
      print("The point is contained within the simplified geometry.")
  # else:
  #     print("The point is not contained within the simplified geometry.")
```

Output -

```
GEOSException: TopologyException: side location conflict at -179.01840000000001 -17.179099999999998. This can occur if the input geometry is invalid.
```

Comment: Add the code you are using to your question, see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Or your question is going to get closed